# How to show that $\int_\Omega \sum\limits_{i,j=1}^n u_{x_i}v_{x_j} dx\le C\int_\Omega |Du||Dv| dx$?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, integral-inequality

$\Omega\subset \mathbb R^n$ is bounded and open. $u,v\in H_0^1(\Omega)$. $Du$ is gradient of $u$.

How to show that $\int_\Omega \sum\limits_{i,j=1}^n u_{x_i}v_{x_j} dx\le C\int_\Omega |Du||Dv| dx$ ?

Comment: Can you remind me your definition of $Du$?

Comment: Are you summing over $i$ and $j$?

Comment: @ellya  Yes, sorry, I missed it .

Comment: @lanse7pty Are you sure that, in the original problem, there is no constant multiplying the RHS?

Comment: @Pedro  Yes, there should be a constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$|Du|=\sqrt{u_{x_1}^2 +\cdots+u_{x_n}^2}\geq c( |u_{x_1}|+\cdots+|u_{x_n}|)$
so $|Du||Dv|\geq c( |u_{x_1}|+\cdots+|u_{x_n}|)(|v_{x_1}|+\cdots+|v_{x_n}|)\geq|\sum u_{x_i}v_{x_j}|$

Comment: Why the constant $c$ disappears in the last step?

Comment: You're right, it should still be there.